# zip does not support timestamps before 1980 aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-codepipeline

We are having projects created with aws codestar. these were working fine. but from today we are facing following issue:

> Unable to upload artifact None referenced by CodeUri parameter of GetCompanyRecords resource.
>
> zip does not support timestamps before 1980

Now when i removed aws-sdk module again it works fine. but when i add it again build fails. i am pretty much worried about this. Here is my lambda function.

```
GetCompanyRecords:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  Handler: index.handler
  Runtime: nodejs6.10
  Role:
    Fn::ImportValue:
      !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
  Timeout: 10
  Events:
    PostEvent:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: /getCompanyRecords
        Method: post
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide details about why you think it related to timestamps before 1980? I don't see any relationship currently. Second, provide some details logs or error message, that we can understand your questions.

Comment: Actually 2nd paragraph 'unable to upload -- 1980' is error logs. Have a look https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J7jwsmsd-WNmMWk4AAWaBSnf7QgSAk0n/view?usp=sharing
I am sure its due to that module because when i removed that from package.json my build works  but where i require that there is issue

Comment: See [this github bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2639) - can you give us more detail on your environment (versions, programming language, etc.)?

Comment: I have seen that bug before. We cannot touch node modules as those are installed internally by aws for lambda functions we dont know what directory struct that uses and how that manges. And details are nodejs, lambda functions and issue is with aws sdk

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It occurs when running `sam pakcage` in a `CodePipeline`. Yesterday morning it worked perfectly fine. Maybe Amazon broke something on their side?

Comment: Update: Seems like someone messed up somewhere down the NPM dependency tree -- https://github.com/feross/ieee754/issues/17

Comment: This CodeBuild forum post also addressed the same issue. 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=274757&tstart=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment following patch fixed my issue:

I added following lines to buildspec.yml after 'npm install'

-ls $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR

-find $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/node_modules -mtime +10950 -exec touch {} ;

As i was having issue just by adding aws-sdk so i want aws to fix to this issue. I am really disappointed aws-sdk is not working with aws..

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to initialize the codebase with git:). It means It's trying to create a zip from git's head but failing

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -am 'First commit'
```